# is Long threadsafe?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

Is this Java class threadsafe?

```
class Counter() {

  private Long counter = 0;

  Long get() { return counter; }

  Long inc() { return ++counter; }
}
```

If not, is it possible to make it threadsafe without using locks explicitly (or the `synchronized` keyword)? If not, then I guess the following is the simplest way to achieve my goal?

```
class Counter() {

  private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

  Long get() { return counter.get(); }

  Long inc() { return counter.incrementAndGet(); }
}
```

Comment: Your first example, aside from being uncompilable, doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I assume you mean `++counter` which should not compile because of the `final`.  Right?

Comment: If you remove the syntax errors and change the variable name from `long` to `counter`, it will indeed not compile because of the `final`, yes.

Answer (score 8):

No, the first example is not thread-safe since `++counter` is not atomic. For example, there is nothing to stop two threads executing `++counter` at the same time and losing one of the increments.

The second example *is* thread-safe, meaning that no increments will get lost. It is worth noting that both `get()` and `inc()` return a value that could well be obsolete by the time the caller receives it.

Comment: His code says `++long` which is not right and `++counter` shouldn't compile with the final, right?

Answer (score 2):

A different answer regarding thread-safey and longs.  A long in Java is 64 bits which take up two separate 32 bit registers.  You have high 32 bits and low 32 bits.  A single write accounts for two non-atomic 32 bit stores.

You can end up with a high 32 bit write from one thread and a low 32 bit write from another thread which could produce a number that is neither from the first thread or second.

Comment: While that is a concern, in this case -- as finally edited -- it's not. The OP is using a `Long`, not a `long`. This instance variable must be unboxed within the method to be incremented, then is reboxed before being stored back in the instance variable. The `long` that is actually incremented only appears on the operand stack of the invoking method.

Comment: @Parisfal Agreed that in this instance it may not be a issue, but is an issue to know about with thread-safety and Long/longs in general.  And regardless of Long or long, the thread-safety failure of incrementing occurs with or without boxing.

Comment: @Parisfal I know the                                                                                        'long' isnt            'thread-safe' ,what about the            'Long'?

Comment: The `Long` is backed by a `long` so you'll have a similar concern.

Answer (score 0):

`Long` is immutable, then **it is** thread-safe. What is **not thread-safe** is the unbox-increment-and-assign required by `inc`, which (properly implemented) is equivalent to:

```
Long inc() { return counter= long.longValue()+1; }
```